# vbscript loop through html form inputs

Tags: html, arrays, forms, loops, vbscript

I'm using VBscript to manipulate html form inputs and putting them into and retrieving from a spreadsheet.

The form itself looks in part like ...

```
    For i = 1 to NumberFigures
        document.write "<input name=""figno" & i & """ type=""text"">"
    Next
```

... which is fine for when i = 1, But I'm not sure how to access this for cases of i > 1 from the relevant function. Extract follows ...

```
    For i = 0 to max
        Figno = "Form1.figno" & i+1 & ".Value"
        arr(i,19) = Figno
    Next
```

This is a smal sample. The resultant assembled array is updated to a spreadsheet. All works well except arr(i,19) is assigned the string value of "Form1.figno1.Value" rather than the value in the input name of figno1 in Form1. To confirm that the form and input works, I tried using the following ...

```
    arr(i,19) = Form1.figno1.Value
```

... which returns the value of input "figno1" for all values of i. So that part seems OK.

Any help greatly appreciated.

R

Update ... have updated the code per suggestion. The portion of the function that accesses the form is below. As it is here, it pulls up at the `arr(j,20) = Form1.children("figname" & j+1).Value` part and gives this error Message: ***Object required: '[object]'***

```
    redim arr(NumberFigures-1,30)
    MsgBox(NumberFigures)
    For j = 0 to NumberFigures-1
        arr(j,0) = date()
        arr(j,1) = time()
        arr(j,2) = requestFlag
        arr(j,3) = requestNo
        arr(j,4) = requestNo
        arr(j,5) = strvar
        arr(j,6) = "New Request"
        arr(j,7) = "DRAFT"
        arr(j,8) = Form1.jobnumber.Value
        arr(j,9) = Form1.cost.Value
        arr(j,10) = Form1.client.Value
        arr(j,11) = Form1.project.Value
        arr(j,12) = Form1.reportNo.Value
        arr(j,13) = Form1.report.Value
        arr(j,14) = Form1.chapterNo.Value
        arr(j,15) = Form1.chapter.Value
        arr(j,16) = NumberFigures
        arr(j,17) = Form1.budget.Value
        arr(j,18) = Form1.required.Value                    
        arr(j,19) = Form1.children("figno" & j+1).Value
        arr(j,20) = Form1.children("figname" & j+1).Value
        arr(j,22) = Form1.children("fig01com" & j+1).Value
        arr(j,23) = Form1.children("fig02com" & j+1).Value

        If arr(j,23) <> "" Then                         
            pos = InStrRev (arr(j,23),"\")
            attachlength = len(arr(j,23)) - pos
            attachname = right(arr(j,23),attachlength)
            arr(j,24) = "\\bne-fs1\admin\Groups\GIS\Requests\" & requestNo & "\" & attachname
        End If

    Next
```

The code in the body ... (table and rows already defined to this point)

```
    document.write "<form name=""Form1"" method=""post"" onsubmit=""blank()"">"
    document.write "<input name=""name"" type=""hidden"" VALUE=""" & strVar & """>"
    document.write "<input name=""jobnumber"" type=""hidden"" value=""" & FigureAdd(0,8) & """>"
    document.write "<input name=""cost"" type=""hidden"" value=""" & FigureAdd(0,9) & """>"
    document.write "<input name=""client"" type=""hidden"" value=""" & FigureAdd(0,10) & """>"
    document.write "<input name=""project"" type=""hidden"" value=""" & FigureAdd(0,11) & """>"
    document.write "<input name=""reportNo"" type=""hidden"" value=""" & FigureAdd(0,12) & """>"
    document.write "<input name=""report"" type=""hidden"" value=""" & FigureAdd(0,13) & """>"
    document.write "<input name=""chapterNo"" type=""hidden"" value=""" & FigureAdd(0,14) & """>"
    document.write "<input name=""chapter"" type=""hidden"" value=""" & FigureAdd(0,15) & """>"
    document.write "<input name=""budget"" type=""hidden"" value=""" & FigureAdd(0,17) & """>"
    document.write "<input name=""required"" type=""hidden"" value=""" & FigureAdd(0,18) & """>"

    For i = 1 to NumberFigures
        document.write "<td align=""center""><input name=""figno" & i & """ type=""text"" size=""5"" value=""figno" & i & """></td>"
        document.write "<td align=""center""><input name=""figname" & i & """ type=""text"" size=""60"" value=""figname" & i & """></td>"
        document.write "<td><textarea rows=""2"" cols=""40"" name=""fig01com" & i & """ form=""Form1"">fig01com" & i & "</textarea></td>"
        document.write "<td><input name=""fig02com" & i & """ type=""file"" size=""30""><input name=""fig03com" & i & """ type=""hidden""></td></tr>"
        document.write "<tr valign=""bottom""><td></td><td></td>"           
    Next

    document.write "</tr></table>"
    document.write "<input type=""button"" onclick=""Test()"" value=""Submit Request""></form>"
```

Comment: For which value of `j` does the error occur? Does `Form1` actually have a child element with the name `"figname" & j+1`? Use your browser's web development tools to inspect the generated HTML.

Comment: It was hanging up on `j=0` ... but if I only had one `Form1.children("figno" & j+1).Value` and kept the others to `Form1.figname1.Value` which is useless but for the sake of testing, then it would hang up on `j=1`. After looking at the generated html (Thanks! never knew I could) I removed the table and it seems to work perfecty. Thank you so kindly for your answer ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Form1.figno1.Value` and `"Form1.figno1.Value"` are two entirely different things. The former is a property of a nested object, whereas the latter is a string. If you want to vary the name when accessing the nested object(s), you need to do it via the `children` collection, like this:

```
For i = 0 to max
  arr(i, 19) = Form1.children("figno" & i+1).Value
Next
```

Comment: OK @Ansgar sorry but I spoke too soon. Only works for the first loop ie when i = 0. Also gets hung up when I add another `arr(i,20) = Form1.children("figname" & i+1).Value`

Comment: Not much I can do about that without seeing your actual code and the HTML it operates on.

Comment: Sorry ... Might have over done it with the code though. What started as an idea has become an animal